# Как создать клавиатуру, которая не будет сразу отправлять?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Создал клавиатуру в своем боте, но она отправляет сразу после нажатия, а мне надо, чтобы она работала как стандартная: пока не нажал отправить, он не отправит, например:

```
клавиатура:
1 2 3 +
4 5 6 -
7 8 9 *
0 . /
```

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия символы появлялись в строке, а не сразу отправлялись боту?

Comment: Вроде бы api таких кнопок подразумевает сразу отправку, т.е. никак это не исправить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В текущей версии Telegram Bot API (Bot API 3.0, 18/05/2017) это не реализовано. Вы можете использовать для этого [встроенную клавиатуру](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), выполняя свои вычисления и после нажатия кнопки <kbd>=</kbd> отправлять сообщение с результатом вычислений пользователю.

> Unlike with custom reply keyboards, pressing buttons on inline keyboards doesn't result in messages sent to the chat.

---

Так же по теме - [Telegram Bot API кастомная клавиатура, отправка нескольких значений в одном сообщении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670761/183842)