# Telegram Bot API кастомная клавиатура, отправка нескольких значений в одном сообщений

Tags: telegram-bot

Появилась необходимость сделать кастомную клавиатуру с цифрами для того, чтобы пользователь вводил число, например 900.

Но тут я столкнулся с другой проблемой, если пользователь начнёт вводить это число, то по факту оно будет отправлено в виде трёх сообщений - "9","0","0".

Есть ли возможность не отправлять сообщение пока пользователь вводит данные, а по нажатию доп.кнопки (например сделать Enter) отправить всё одним сообщением?

Comment: Такой возможности нету. Можно, конечно, наваять что-то с помощью [inline-клавиатуры](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), но подменять набираемый текст в поле ввода сообщения вряд ли выйдет.

Comment: Спасибо. Печально конечно, но не смертельно =)

Comment: Гляньте, как реализована цифровая клавиатура в https://t.me/calculator_bot _(ничего необычного, просто калькулятор через телеграм :D)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается с помощью *InlineKeyboard*. Набираемые пользователем цифры можно записывать в *caption* или в тело самого сообщения, которому будет принадлежать клавиатура. После нажатия кнопки *Enter* обрабатывайте *caption* или текст сообщения с сохранёнными цифрами, при этом отпадает необходимость отправлять сообщение как при использовании обычной клавиатуры.